# Rails: Use a value of a field as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, helper, button-to

I'm building a quizz application in which the user can enter the correct answer into a number field. I want to use the value in this field as a parameter in the button_to method to create a new answer. If i click the button, it does create a new answer with the first two parameters as attributes, but the attribute for givenanswer is empty. I don't get an error, it just doesn't set my givenanswer parameter as an attribute.

How do i get a value in a field and use it as a parameter? Should i use a helper? (i'm new to rails and haven't made use of helpers yet).

*Questionscontroller*

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def showquestion
    @question = Question.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  # . . .
```

*showquestion*

```
views/questions/showquestion/1
    <b>Question:</b>
    <%=h @question.word %>
<b>1:</b>
<%=h @question.ans1 %>

<b>2:</b>
<%=h @question.ans2 %>

<b>The correct answer is number: </b>
<%=number_field :givenanswer, params[:givenanswer]%>

<%= button_to 'add answer', {:controller => "answers", :action => "create", 
                :question_id => @question.id, :questionfinished => Time.now, :givenanswer => params[:givenanswer] }  %>
```

*Answercontroller*

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /answers
  # POST /answers.json
  def create
  question =Question.find(params[:question_id])
  questionfinished = params[:questionfinished]
  givenanswer = params[:givenanswer]
   @answer = Answer.new(question: question, questionfinished: questionfinished, givenanswer: givenanswer)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @answer, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @answer }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

UPDATE:
I tried to use it in a form and it seemed to work: now i do have an attribute givenanswer for Answer objects.
however, it always stores a 0, whatever number I insert in the form.

```
 <%= form_tag(:controller => "answers", :action => "create", :question_id => @question.id, :questionfinished => Time.now, :givenanswer => :givenanswer) do %>
   <p>
    <b>Het juiste antwoord is nummer: </b>
    <%=number_field :givenanswer, params[:givenanswer]%>
   </p>

   <p><%= submit_tag("voegantwoordtoemetformtag")%></P>
<% end %>
```

Comment: please paste the params value ..

Comment: In view Instead of this .. <%=number_field :givenanswer, params[:givenanswer]%>  do this .. <%=number_field :givenanswer%>

In button_to do this ..  { params[:givenanswer] =>:givenanswer}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather use a form for this, but if you really want to, you can dynamically change the value using javascript

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to use a form but i think i did something wrong (but i have no clue what)? I updated this post and added the new code in an update